# "APK was defined multiple times" , app fails to install with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, compilation, apk, failed-installation

My app was installing just fine... installing and reinstalling for testing, etc.  But now it won't install anymore... and Android Studio says,

> Application Installation Failed
>
> Installation failed with message Failed to
>
> finalize session :
>
> INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split
>
> lib_slice_3_apk was defined multiple times.
>
> It is possible that this issue is resolved by
>
> uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is
>
> present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the
>
> application data!
>
> Do you want to  uninstall the existing
>
> application?
>
> [CANCEL]     [OK]

I tried uninstalling the app from my phone, but it still won't re-install.

Also, I tried installing it fresh on an emulator where it had never been installed before, and that did not work either.

I suppose I must have inadvertently messed up some compile-related setting that I don't understand (but I haven't been doing anything like that).  I don't have a knowledge of the compile process, and pretty much depend on Android Studio to do that.

I have been working on a "sister" app to this one... where I copied some libraries (.jar files such as zixng.jar from [project root]\app\libs) from this app to the other app.  And that other app is installed on my phone also... but then again, it's not on the emulator... so I guess that's not the problem. Merp.

Thanks for any suggestions or possible explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to clean & then Rebuild the project again. To do so please go to Build menu, both the tools are present their.

If issue not solved with that than try to invalidate caches & restart Android Studio from File menu -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: That worked thanks!  I did "make" and "sync with gradle" but forgot about cleaning.  Good thing I don't have to actually understand the error. Whew!